# What's the music from Naruto Shippuden in episode 175/500

Tags: naruto, music

What is the name of the song in episode 175, in which the naruto ends a prayer at Jiraya's grave?
And this song also appears in episode 500, when the naruto asks Iruka to be his father at his wedding?

Comment: Welcome to A&M! Could you include a timestamp of where in the episodes the music starts?

Answer (score 1):

''Guts to never give up'' or ''Jiraiya's death theme''

[source](https://www.narutoforums.org/threads/post-all-what-soundtrack-song-questions-here-part-1.814526/page-15)